# How can we write a udf in pyspark for parsing complex column data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have column values which is of the form of
{"1":"mediaMaaadadeftch||OAISAOID|true|ModsVersio|67900|clk|true|PPOOOS|20220501164113|34958|38177557..}

This is not a json format, some values are pipe separated and some are double pipe separated, how can we write a udf which breaks this value and convert into multiple columns.

col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|..
1|mediaMaaadadeftch|OAISAOID|true| ..

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing udf , you can do it by csv file

store the data in a csv file and load it

```
>>> df1 = spark.read.load("/path_to/sample.csv",format="csv", sep="|")
>>> df1.show()
+--------------------+----+--------+----+----------+-----+---+----+------+--------------+-----+--------+
|                 _c0| _c1|     _c2| _c3|       _c4|  _c5|_c6| _c7|   _c8|           _c9| _c10|    _c11|
+--------------------+----+--------+----+----------+-----+---+----+------+--------------+-----+--------+
|"1":"mediaMaaadad...|null|OAISAOID|true|ModsVersio|67900|clk|true|PPOOOS|20220501164113|34958|38177557|
+--------------------+----+--------+----+----------+-----+---+----+------+--------------+-----+--------+
```

columns with double pipe "||" will be null , so if you don't need those columns you can remove them

Comment: data is very big, csv creating is not possible.